# Slow/Never loading images/ajax Windows Server 2012 R2, TFS2013

Tags: ajax, iis, server-configuration, iis-8.5

Ref: [Slow serving Ajax / Images, IIS 7.5 / .net / Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874556/slow-serving-ajax-images-iis-7-5-net-windows-7)

The question linked above describes the symptoms I am seeing exactly.

Using TFS2013 or SmarterTrack 9.5 on Windows Server 2012 R2 with IIS 8.5.

When I first load a page from either application everything seems fine and works fine for a little while.  After locking my PC and coming back later any pages in either application will no longer load.

The progress indicator on the browser tab shows that it's still doing stuff but the images never load.

Closing the browser and re-opening resolves the problem temporarily but it will return when the session times out again.

Does anyone know a pure server config solution to this problem?

Comment: Have you found the solution to the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not.  It seems to only happen on our internal server and only intermittently.